# selenium Unable to locate element using methods: cannot find elements by id, css_selector, xpath, link text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to scrape the data in [this](http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/) DB. I did ask a similar question about this previously, but my current question is specific/I am starting to understand the issue more.

So far, with selenium, I can type 22663 into the 'search by plant-based food' field, then click 'food-disease associations' underneath, and then click submit, as shown here:

[image]

it's the next page that I have the issue with, I cannot click 'Plant-Disease Associations'.

I have tried numerous ideas from other SO posts:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#binary = FirefoxBinary('/Users/kela/Desktop/scripts/scraping/geckodriver')
url = 'http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/kela/Desktop/scripts/scraping/geckodriver')
driver.get(url)

#input the tax ID
element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")

#click food-disease association
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')

#click submit
submit_xpath = '/html/body/form/p[2]/input[1]'
destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_xpath)
destination_page_link.click()


# this is where it goes wrong
#click plant-disease associations
#table_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="likeabutton"]')
#driver.find_element_by_link_text("plant-disease").click()
#driver.find_element_by_link_text("nutrichem12587_disease.tsv").click()


 #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@onclick'nutrichem12587_disease.tsv']").click()

#values = []
#for i in table_data.find_element_by_tag_name('Plant-Disease associations'):
#    values.append(i.text)
#print(value)


#span = table_data.find_element_by_tag_name('Plant-Disease associations')
#print(span)

#select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]"))
#select.click()
#submit_xpath = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/span'
#submit_xpath = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]'
#destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_xpath)
#destination_page_link.click()

#element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='plant-disease']")
#element.select_by_value('Plant-Disease associations')


#xpath2 = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div'
#destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)
#destination_page_link.click()

#xpath2 = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/span'
#destination_page_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)
#destination_page_link.click()
```

I've commented out all the lines that I've tried and don't work. You can see I've tried multiple options as suggested on different SO posts, I'm aware that there are a lot of similar questions out there, but none of the solutions seem to work for me; all the errors are basically the same, 'cannot find element' (e.g. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: nutrichem12587_disease.tsv)

Can someone please help me click on the 'Plant-Disease association' button. I'm wondering, is it because the page that I'm trying to click on is .php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inside a frame. You need to switch to that

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="Submit"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="plant-disease"]').click()
```